# Bootstrap won't work in Redmine plugin

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, redmine, redmine-plugins

I've spent hours trying to use bootstrap for my rails web app, but it's doing absolutely nothing! I can't call any classes for it!

Here's my index.html.erb:

```
<div class="center">
  <h1>Welcome to the User Database</h1>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h2>
  This is the home page for the User Database.
  </h2>

  **<%= link_to "Add new entry", new_user_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <%= button_to "Search", users_search_path, class: "button", :method => :get %>**
</div>

<!-- User Image -->
<div class="center">
  <%= image_tag('user.jpg', :plugin => 'users') %>
</div>

<!-- Style sheet -->
<% content_for :header_tags do %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style', :plugin => 'users' %>
<% end %>
```

Notice the bolded code...the link_to line COMPLETELY IGNORES the bootstrap class, like it doesn't even exist! The button_to line works completely fine...

My Gemfile includes bootstrap (yes, I ran bundle install since updating it):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

if Gem::Version.new(Bundler::VERSION) < Gem::Version.new('1.5.0')
  abort "Redmine requires Bundler 1.5.0 or higher (you're using #{Bundler::VERSION}).\nPlease update with 'gem update bundler'."
end

#Trying to get bootstrap...?
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'

gem "rails", "4.2.3"
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 3.1.3"

...
```

Also, my css file most certainly includes bootstrap:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

/* universal */

body {
  padding-top: 0px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

...
```

I also even included in bootstrap in my application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

It just won't work! The only thing I can think of is that I am building my rails app as part of a plugin for Redmine, and that's somehow messing everything up...but I don't see how!

UPDATE:

I tried doing this:

```
<% content_for :header_tags do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :plugin => 'users' %>
<% end %>
```

But I get this cryptic error!

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/plugin_assets/users/stylesheets/bootstrap"):
```

I don't understand what that means. Why is it looking for bootstrap file in stylesheets directory?? Google has never heard of this error message!

Comment: First off, not sure what the `:plugin => 'users'` is attempting to do, but remove that.

Second, do you have bootstrap's container div set up in your layout file?

Comment: I need that line because my application is a plugin for redmine. See: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugin_Tutorial#Improving-the-plugin-views       And I don't have any layout file, that's all I have. I don't even know what bootstrap's container div is....? i'm a complete noobie to this stuff

Comment: Ah, indeed.  Sorry.  You may not need the container div.  But check out the docs here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

You say the `button_to` renders as a bootstrap button?

Comment: No, it just renders as a normal button, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: I see.  Not familiar with Redmine, but I still may be able to help.  What's the name of the css file that you're @importing bootstrap and bootstrap-sprockets into?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I made a new file called dang.scss in assets/stylesheets directory. I update that stylesheet_link_tag to be 'dang' when I try to get it to work, but it just searches for 'dang.css' instead of 'dang.scss' and I don't understand how to make it work

Comment: The webpage loads (without bootstrap), but the error it throws in the log is: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/plugin_assets/users/stylesheets/dang.css"): <----that plugin_assets directory contains dang.scss, but not dang.css

Comment: You have asked an almost completely identical question a few hours ago. Re-asking the same question to attract answers is not an acceptable behaviour on StackExchange.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redmine Plugin Development: can't get bootstrap to do anything :(](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001092/redmine-plugin-development-cant-get-bootstrap-to-do-anything)

Comment: Yeah I tried putting in the update at the bottom but somehow it created a whole new question, the old question can just be deleted. There I deleted it

Comment: You can delete it yourself.

Comment: The scss file isn't being precompiled into css.  Check out  config/initializers/assets.rb and add /plugin_assets/users/stylesheets/dang.scss to config.assets.precompile like so:
`config.assets.precompile += %w( /plugin_assets/users/stylesheets/dang.scss )`
That may work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint, but if you're building a Redmine plugin using Bootstrap, you're doing it wrong. A plugin (no matter for which platform) should offer a seamless user experience with regards to the host platform itself. Since Redmine is not using Bootstrap, there's no reason you should use it for your plugin.

Instead, you should have a look at the `app/views` directory in Redmine and use the same HTML elements in your plugin. You'll have a more seamless UI and less need for custom CSS... Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, very interesting. Thanks for the insight. I guess it's true what they say: don't use a screwdriver to hammer in a nail :)

Answer (score 1):

Redmine does not support the asset pipeline (see [here](http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/31117), 4 year old conversation), which means you cannot use sass/scss files here. You need first to get regular css / js files and import each of them manually in your view.

If you really wish to use bootstrap, you can first install the [redmine_bootstrap_kit](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_bootstrap_kit) plugin which provides helpers for you in order to make it more convenient (I am not the owner of this).

For information:

Plugin `assets` directory is automatically copied each time you run Redmine in the `public/plugin_assets/your_plugin` folder.

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style', :plugin => 'users' %>`
Will look for `style.css` file located in `public/plugin_assets/users/stylesheets/style.js`

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'script', :plugin => 'users' %>`
Will look for `script.js` file located in `public/plugin_assets/users/javascripts/script.js`

Please note, generally `.js` and `.css` files contain links to additional resources (images, fonts...). Then you need to includes these resources as well in your `assets/images` / `assets/fonts`... and make sure the relative paths mentioned in the `.js` and `.css` files remain valid.